# Add all objects using loop - only last value added

Tags: javascript, loops

What I am trying to do is have an output that looks like this fiddle with 4 pieces of a donut chart

http://jsfiddle.net/chaninlee/zZYxY/

Unfortunately, I “cheated” here because I wrote:

```
{label : featureSet.features[0].attributes['STATE_NAME'] ,value : featureSet.features[0].attributes['MED_AGE']},
{label : featureSet.features[1].attributes['STATE_NAME'] ,value : featureSet.features[1].attributes['MED_AGE']},
{label : featureSet.features[2].attributes['STATE_NAME'] ,value : featureSet.features[2].attributes['MED_AGE']},
{label : featureSet.features[3].attributes['STATE_NAME'] ,value : featureSet.features[3].attributes['MED_AGE']}
```

I thought I could return all outputs correctly by writing the code like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/chaninlee/T8XZM/

It looks like using,

```
{label : featureSet.features[i].attributes['STATE_NAME'] ,value : featureSet.features[i].attributes['MED_AGE']}
```

will loop through in my case 0-3 but uses the last [3] output so the entire donut chart is represented by one state and median age.

I would like to know how to do this so I don't have to type things out for each [i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current code is:

```
for (var i=0; i<featureSet.features.length;i++)
{
    // Each loop re-assigns a new object to the SAME variable
    // which overwrites the previous value ..
    output = {label : featureSet.features[i].attributes['STATE_NAME'],
              value : featureSet.features[i].attributes['MED_AGE']};        
    console.log(output);
}

// Only the CURRENT (LAST) value assigned to the output variable
// inside the loop is used to create an array of one element.
Morris.Donut({
    element: 'donut-example',
    data: [output]
});
```

The code should look more like this:

```
var data = [];
for (var i=0; i<featureSet.features.length;i++)
{
    // Create new row/output object ..
    var output = {label : featureSet.features[i].attributes['STATE_NAME'],
                  value : featureSet.features[i].attributes['MED_AGE']};        
    // .. and then store the created object in an array
    data.push(output);
}

Morris.Donut({
    element: 'donut-example',
    // Use created array
    data: data
});
```